# Letting user dynamically create fields using Settings API

Tags: settings-api

I created a settings page, using the Settings API, following [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/).

Now I want to have a button that lets users dynamically add fields, similar to the way it is done [in this other one](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/).

I don't want to try to "merge" these two things together. There must be a right way to do this. Can someone give me a clue, how to achieve this?

I already [found this](http://pippinsplugins.com/how-i-built-settings-system-easy-digital-downloads/) in Pippin's Plugins, where he creates an array for his setting fields and displays them with a foreach-loop. But I'm not shure how this can help me.

```
/**
 * This function introduces the theme options into the 'Appearance' menu and into a top-level 
 * 'Sandbox Theme' menu.
 */
function sandbox_example_theme_menu() {

    add_theme_page(
        'Sandbox Theme',                    // The title to be displayed in the browser window for this page.
        'Sandbox Theme',                    // The text to be displayed for this menu item
        'administrator',                    // Which type of users can see this menu item
        'sandbox_theme_options',            // The unique ID - that is, the slug - for this menu item
        'sandbox_theme_display'             // The name of the function to call when rendering this menu's page
    );

    add_menu_page(
        'Sandbox Theme',                    // The value used to populate the browser's title bar when the menu page is active
        'Sandbox Theme',                    // The text of the menu in the administrator's sidebar
        'administrator',                    // What roles are able to access the menu
        'sandbox_theme_menu',               // The ID used to bind submenu items to this menu 
        'sandbox_theme_display'             // The callback function used to render this menu
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'sandbox_theme_menu',               // The ID of the top-level menu page to which this submenu item belongs
        __( 'Display Options', 'sandbox' ),         // The value used to populate the browser's title bar when the menu page is active
        __( 'Display Options', 'sandbox' ),                 // The label of this submenu item displayed in the menu
        'administrator',                    // What roles are able to access this submenu item
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',    // The ID used to represent this submenu item
        'sandbox_theme_display'             // The callback function used to render the options for this submenu item
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'sandbox_theme_menu',
        __( 'Social Options', 'sandbox' ),
        __( 'Social Options', 'sandbox' ),
        'administrator',
        'sandbox_theme_social_options',
        create_function( null, 'sandbox_theme_display( "social_options" );' )
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'sandbox_theme_menu',
        __( 'Input Examples', 'sandbox' ),
        __( 'Input Examples', 'sandbox' ),
        'administrator',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        create_function( null, 'sandbox_theme_display( "input_examples" );' )
    );


} // end sandbox_example_theme_menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sandbox_example_theme_menu' );

/**
 * Renders a simple page to display for the theme menu defined above.
 */
function sandbox_theme_display( $active_tab = '' ) {
?>
    <!-- Create a header in the default WordPress 'wrap' container -->
    <div class="wrap">

        <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sandbox Theme Options', 'sandbox' ); ?></h2>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <?php if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {
            $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];
        } else if( $active_tab == 'social_options' ) {
            $active_tab = 'social_options';
        } else if( $active_tab == 'input_examples' ) {
            $active_tab = 'input_examples';
        } else {
            $active_tab = 'display_options';
        } // end if/else ?>

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=sandbox_theme_options&tab=display_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'display_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"><?php _e( 'Display Options', 'sandbox' ); ?></a>
            <a href="?page=sandbox_theme_options&tab=social_options" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'social_options' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"><?php _e( 'Social Options', 'sandbox' ); ?></a>
            <a href="?page=sandbox_theme_options&tab=input_examples" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'input_examples' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"><?php _e( 'Input Examples', 'sandbox' ); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php

                if( $active_tab == 'display_options' ) {

                    settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );

                } elseif( $active_tab == 'social_options' ) {

                    settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );

                } else {

                    settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

                } // end if/else

                submit_button();

            ?>
        </form>

    </div><!-- /.wrap -->
<?php
} // end sandbox_theme_display

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Setting Registration
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 


/**
 * Provides default values for the Social Options.
 */
function sandbox_theme_default_social_options() {

    $defaults = array(
        'twitter'       =>  '',
        'facebook'      =>  '',
        'googleplus'    =>  '',
    );

    return apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_social_options', $defaults );

} // end sandbox_theme_default_social_options

/**
 * Provides default values for the Display Options.
 */
function sandbox_theme_default_display_options() {

    $defaults = array(
        'show_header'       =>  '',
        'show_content'      =>  '',
        'show_footer'       =>  '',
    );

    return apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_display_options', $defaults );

} // end sandbox_theme_default_display_options

/**
 * Provides default values for the Input Options.
 */
function sandbox_theme_default_input_options() {

    $defaults = array(
        'input_example'     =>  '',
        'textarea_example'  =>  '',
        'checkbox_example'  =>  '',
        'radio_example'     =>  '',
        'time_options'      =>  'default'   
    );

    return apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_input_options', $defaults );

} // end sandbox_theme_default_input_options

/**
 * Initializes the theme's display options page by registering the Sections,
 * Fields, and Settings.
 *
 * This function is registered with the 'admin_init' hook.
 */ 
function sandbox_initialize_theme_options() {

    // If the theme options don't exist, create them.
    if( false == get_option( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' ) ) {  
        add_option( 'sandbox_theme_display_options', apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_display_options', sandbox_theme_default_display_options() ) );
    } // end if

    // First, we register a section. This is necessary since all future options must belong to a 
    add_settings_section(
        'general_settings_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        __( 'Display Options', 'sandbox' ),     // Title to be displayed on the administration page
        'sandbox_general_options_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
        'sandbox_theme_display_options'     // Page on which to add this section of options
    );

    // Next, we'll introduce the fields for toggling the visibility of content elements.
    add_settings_field( 
        'show_header',                      // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme
        __( 'Header', 'sandbox' ),                          // The label to the left of the option interface element
        'sandbox_toggle_header_callback',   // The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',    // The page on which this option will be displayed
        'general_settings_section',         // The name of the section to which this field belongs
        array(                              // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.
            __( 'Activate this setting to display the header.', 'sandbox' ),
        )
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'show_content',                     
        __( 'Content', 'sandbox' ),             
        'sandbox_toggle_content_callback',  
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',                    
        'general_settings_section',         
        array(                              
            __( 'Activate this setting to display the content.', 'sandbox' ),
        )
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'show_footer',                      
        __( 'Footer', 'sandbox' ),              
        'sandbox_toggle_footer_callback',   
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',        
        'general_settings_section',         
        array(                              
            __( 'Activate this setting to display the footer.', 'sandbox' ),
        )
    );

    // Finally, we register the fields with WordPress
    register_setting(
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',
        'sandbox_theme_display_options'
    );

} // end sandbox_initialize_theme_options
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options' );

/**
 * Initializes the theme's social options by registering the Sections,
 * Fields, and Settings.
 *
 * This function is registered with the 'admin_init' hook.
 */ 
function sandbox_theme_intialize_social_options() {

    if( false == get_option( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' ) ) {   
        add_option( 'sandbox_theme_social_options', apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_social_options', sandbox_theme_default_social_options() ) );
    } // end if

    add_settings_section(
        'social_settings_section',          // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        __( 'Social Options', 'sandbox' ),      // Title to be displayed on the administration page
        'sandbox_social_options_callback',  // Callback used to render the description of the section
        'sandbox_theme_social_options'      // Page on which to add this section of options
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'twitter',                      
        'Twitter',                          
        'sandbox_twitter_callback', 
        'sandbox_theme_social_options', 
        'social_settings_section'           
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'facebook',                     
        'Facebook',                         
        'sandbox_facebook_callback',    
        'sandbox_theme_social_options', 
        'social_settings_section'           
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'googleplus',                       
        'Google+',                          
        'sandbox_googleplus_callback',  
        'sandbox_theme_social_options', 
        'social_settings_section'           
    );

    register_setting(
        'sandbox_theme_social_options',
        'sandbox_theme_social_options',
        'sandbox_theme_sanitize_social_options'
    );

} // end sandbox_theme_intialize_social_options
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sandbox_theme_intialize_social_options' );

/**
 * Initializes the theme's input example by registering the Sections,
 * Fields, and Settings. This particular group of options is used to demonstration
 * validation and sanitization.
 *
 * This function is registered with the 'admin_init' hook.
 */ 
function sandbox_theme_initialize_input_examples() {

    if( false == get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' ) ) {   
        add_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples', apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_default_input_options', sandbox_theme_default_input_options() ) );
    } // end if

    add_settings_section(
        'input_examples_section',
        __( 'Input Examples', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_input_examples_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples'
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'Input Element',                        
        __( 'Input Element', 'sandbox' ),                           
        'sandbox_input_element_callback',   
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples', 
        'input_examples_section'            
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'Textarea Element',                     
        __( 'Textarea Element', 'sandbox' ),                            
        'sandbox_textarea_element_callback',    
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples', 
        'input_examples_section'            
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'Checkbox Element',
        __( 'Checkbox Element', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_checkbox_element_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        'input_examples_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'Radio Button Elements',
        __( 'Radio Button Elements', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_radio_element_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        'input_examples_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'Select Element',
        __( 'Select Element', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_select_element_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        'input_examples_section'
    );

    register_setting(
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        'sandbox_theme_input_examples',
        'sandbox_theme_validate_input_examples'
    );

} // end sandbox_theme_initialize_input_examples
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sandbox_theme_initialize_input_examples' );

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Section Callbacks
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 

/**
 * This function provides a simple description for the General Options page. 
 *
 * It's called from the 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options' function by being passed as a parameter
 * in the add_settings_section function.
 */
function sandbox_general_options_callback() {
    echo '<p>' . __( 'Select which areas of content you wish to display.', 'sandbox' ) . '</p>';
} // end sandbox_general_options_callback

/**
 * This function provides a simple description for the Social Options page. 
 *
 * It's called from the 'sandbox_theme_intialize_social_options' function by being passed as a parameter
 * in the add_settings_section function.
 */
function sandbox_social_options_callback() {
    echo '<p>' . __( 'Provide the URL to the social networks you\'d like to display.', 'sandbox' ) . '</p>';
} // end sandbox_general_options_callback

/**
 * This function provides a simple description for the Input Examples page.
 *
 * It's called from the 'sandbox_theme_intialize_input_examples_options' function by being passed as a parameter
 * in the add_settings_section function.
 */
function sandbox_input_examples_callback() {
    echo '<p>' . __( 'Provides examples of the five basic element types.', 'sandbox' ) . '</p>';
} // end sandbox_general_options_callback

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Field Callbacks
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 

/**
 * This function renders the interface elements for toggling the visibility of the header element.
 * 
 * It accepts an array or arguments and expects the first element in the array to be the description
 * to be displayed next to the checkbox.
 */
function sandbox_toggle_header_callback($args) {

    // First, we read the options collection
    $options = get_option('sandbox_theme_display_options');

    // Next, we update the name attribute to access this element's ID in the context of the display options array
    // We also access the show_header element of the options collection in the call to the checked() helper function
    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="show_header" name="sandbox_theme_display_options[show_header]" value="1" ' . checked( 1, isset( $options['show_header'] ) ? $options['show_header'] : 0, false ) . '/>'; 

    // Here, we'll take the first argument of the array and add it to a label next to the checkbox
    $html .= '<label for="show_header">&nbsp;'  . $args[0] . '</label>'; 

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_toggle_header_callback

function sandbox_toggle_content_callback($args) {

    $options = get_option('sandbox_theme_display_options');

    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="show_content" name="sandbox_theme_display_options[show_content]" value="1" ' . checked( 1, isset( $options['show_content'] ) ? $options['show_content'] : 0, false ) . '/>'; 
    $html .= '<label for="show_content">&nbsp;'  . $args[0] . '</label>'; 

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_toggle_content_callback

function sandbox_toggle_footer_callback($args) {

    $options = get_option('sandbox_theme_display_options');

    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="show_footer" name="sandbox_theme_display_options[show_footer]" value="1" ' . checked( 1, isset( $options['show_footer'] ) ? $options['show_footer'] : 0, false ) . '/>'; 
    $html .= '<label for="show_footer">&nbsp;'  . $args[0] . '</label>'; 

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_toggle_footer_callback

function sandbox_twitter_callback() {

    // First, we read the social options collection
    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );

    // Next, we need to make sure the element is defined in the options. If not, we'll set an empty string.
    $url = '';
    if( isset( $options['twitter'] ) ) {
        $url = esc_url( $options['twitter'] );
    } // end if

    // Render the output
    echo '<input type="text" id="twitter" name="sandbox_theme_social_options[twitter]" value="' . $url . '" />';

} // end sandbox_twitter_callback

function sandbox_facebook_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );

    $url = '';
    if( isset( $options['facebook'] ) ) {
        $url = esc_url( $options['facebook'] );
    } // end if

    // Render the output
    echo '<input type="text" id="facebook" name="sandbox_theme_social_options[facebook]" value="' . $url . '" />';

} // end sandbox_facebook_callback

function sandbox_googleplus_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_social_options' );

    $url = '';
    if( isset( $options['googleplus'] ) ) {
        $url = esc_url( $options['googleplus'] );
    } // end if

    // Render the output
    echo '<input type="text" id="googleplus" name="sandbox_theme_social_options[googleplus]" value="' . $url . '" />';

} // end sandbox_googleplus_callback

function sandbox_input_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    // Render the output
    echo '<input type="text" id="input_example" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[input_example]" value="' . $options['input_example'] . '" />';

} // end sandbox_input_element_callback

function sandbox_textarea_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    // Render the output
    echo '<textarea id="textarea_example" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[textarea_example]" rows="5" cols="50">' . $options['textarea_example'] . '</textarea>';

} // end sandbox_textarea_element_callback

function sandbox_checkbox_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_example" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[checkbox_example]" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options['checkbox_example'], false ) . '/>';
    $html .= '&nbsp;';
    $html .= '<label for="checkbox_example">This is an example of a checkbox</label>';

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_checkbox_element_callback

function sandbox_radio_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    $html = '<input type="radio" id="radio_example_one" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[radio_example]" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options['radio_example'], false ) . '/>';
    $html .= '&nbsp;';
    $html .= '<label for="radio_example_one">Option One</label>';
    $html .= '&nbsp;';
    $html .= '<input type="radio" id="radio_example_two" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[radio_example]" value="2"' . checked( 2, $options['radio_example'], false ) . '/>';
    $html .= '&nbsp;';
    $html .= '<label for="radio_example_two">Option Two</label>';

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_radio_element_callback

function sandbox_select_element_callback() {

    $options = get_option( 'sandbox_theme_input_examples' );

    $html = '<select id="time_options" name="sandbox_theme_input_examples[time_options]">';
        $html .= '<option value="default">' . __( 'Select a time option...', 'sandbox' ) . '</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="never"' . selected( $options['time_options'], 'never', false) . '>' . __( 'Never', 'sandbox' ) . '</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="sometimes"' . selected( $options['time_options'], 'sometimes', false) . '>' . __( 'Sometimes', 'sandbox' ) . '</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="always"' . selected( $options['time_options'], 'always', false) . '>' . __( 'Always', 'sandbox' ) . '</option>';   $html .= '</select>';

    echo $html;

} // end sandbox_radio_element_callback

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Setting Callbacks
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 

/**
 * Sanitization callback for the social options. Since each of the social options are text inputs,
 * this function loops through the incoming option and strips all tags and slashes from the value
 * before serializing it.
 *  
 * @params  $input  The unsanitized collection of options.
 *
 * @returns         The collection of sanitized values.
 */
function sandbox_theme_sanitize_social_options( $input ) {

    // Define the array for the updated options
    $output = array();

    // Loop through each of the options sanitizing the data
    foreach( $input as $key => $val ) {

        if( isset ( $input[$key] ) ) {
            $output[$key] = esc_url_raw( strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[$key] ) ) );
        } // end if 

    } // end foreach

    // Return the new collection
    return apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_sanitize_social_options', $output, $input );

} // end sandbox_theme_sanitize_social_options

function sandbox_theme_validate_input_examples( $input ) {

    // Create our array for storing the validated options
    $output = array();

    // Loop through each of the incoming options
    foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

        // Check to see if the current option has a value. If so, process it.
        if( isset( $input[$key] ) ) {

            // Strip all HTML and PHP tags and properly handle quoted strings
            $output[$key] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[ $key ] ) );

        } // end if

    } // end foreach

    // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
    return apply_filters( 'sandbox_theme_validate_input_examples', $output, $input );

} // end sandbox_theme_validate_input_examples
?>
```

Comment: Would be better if you presented your code and the exact point where you're getting stuck.

Comment: This is my code. Its exactly the code from the tutorial. Im not stuck, I'm just uncertain what to do next.

Comment: Ok, but what are you uncertain about in those five hundred lines? Tip: indent your code so it's easier to understand, for you and the reader.

Comment: It is indented, but it got lost, while copying it here. These 500 lines are fine. Im not shure how I would do a repeating field. Lets say I want a text field, like the one in tab 3. But I want the user add a duplicate of it as often as he wants. Then I want to get the values from the database and display as much paragraphs as the user created (I know this is a dumb example, its just to illustrate the problem). Now I really dont know how to implement that into what I got so far.

Comment: Indented the code for you(when copying from GIT, use the RAW view, paste it into an editor and tab all the code in once more, then you can paste a copy of the code straight into a question/answer without having to do anything else).